# AJAX Comments with Jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I own a flash game website and I want my users to be able to post comments without having the page refreshed.
Could someone give me an example?

```
function addcomment($uid, $gid, $text){
    connect();
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`uid`, `gid`, `text`, `date`) VALUES ($uid, $gid, '$text', '$date'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not put SQL code in your view pages.

Try to use [this plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to manage the ajax form submission.

Comment: what do you mean by "you should not put SQL code in your view pages"?

Comment: @David - If you are putting SQL code into your view pages (or, in this case, your JavaScript) you open up an enormous security hole. JavaScript can easily be retrieved by any person who has access to your website and they can rewrite the SQL to do whatever they want. (Think, DROP ALL type statements.) It's very bad to do from a security perspective.

Comment: so basicly, i cant have a form that runs a sql query without interrupting the game on the page?

like say i use the method get on ajax and addslashes then run the query...

Comment: I believe bluefoot is saying to not to have the sql code generated in the javascript then passed to the server to execute. Probably, the PHP code you showed was mistaken for javascript. However, your PHP code might still be open to this sort of attack. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Yes. Do not generate SQL code into JS. Also, don't put your SQL code in php views either. This is spreading around all your business code, and it's maintenance will get more and more difficult. You should concentrate all your SQL code in a PHP script or in a set of PHP scripts. So basically, your ajax form submits to a PHP script that handles the SQL and returns the results to the view. More info [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form via jQuery is often as simple as

```
<input type=submit value="submit"
 onClick="$.post('save_comment.php', $('form#example').serialize())">
```

This triggers an ordinary POST request, and in your save_comment.php script you just add:

```
<?php
  addcomment($_SESSION["uid"], $_POST["gid"], $_POST["comment_field"]);
```

Note that you need `mysql_real_escape_query()` around the variables here - or in your `addcomment()` function (where it belongs).

Add a jQuery `success:` callback if your comment saving script returns something that you want to inject into the html page (e.g. formatted comment or error message string).